# How to insert a function into my code block

Tags: excel, vba, function

I would like to insert a function in this vba code block. What I am trying to do here is look for matches based on two criteria. The first criteria is their ID(Col:B) and the second is the amount they paid (Col:C). The idea being that the function would then cycle through the columns referenced and return the index function until the end of the data.

The VBA code block is listed below:

Update:

> ```
> Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
> For i = Last To 1 Step -1
>     If (Cells(i, "B").Value) > 0 And (Cells(i, "C").Value) > 0 Then
>     Cells(i, "D") = "=IFERROR(INDEX($F$2:$F$500,MATCH(1,INDEX((B2 = $G$2:$G$500)*(C2=$H$2:$H$500),0,1),0)), No Match)"
>     End If
> Next i
> ```

This will now paste the function into the cells. I am having two problems:

1. I need to figure out how to use a range in the "D" column so that it adjusts the cell selection one down as the function pastes down. I know the "Range" does this, but I want it to stop when there is no longer any data, range will continue past the end of the data to the cell selected for the range end, and the way it's set up now stops at the end of the data.
2. The "No Match" part isn't transfering over because it has something to do with the quotes. It's reconginizing it as something different than text.

Comment: Do you want the function itself inserted into the cells, or just the result of it's calculations?

Comment: Just the results of the calculations.

Comment: Now that I think about it, either way is fine. Would the function be entered into the VBA as "text"?

Comment: you might be able to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.<your function>`. You might be able to look around [here](https://spreadsheeto.com/vba-vlookup/) for help.

Comment: I tried that, that's what I have been fighting with and don't have time now.

Comment: Then why bother at all? Just move on and actually, I am familiar with arrays and functions, I posted a function i created in excel in the comment. I am just trying to convert it to a VBA format, that's all I was asking for.